# Ellipse naturally associated with a polygon

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, integral-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

My colleagues and I have stumbled onto a way to associate an ellipse, or equivalently a positive definite symmetric matrix, to a polygon that is different from other better known ways. We want to know if anyone has ever seen this before. Before describing this, I do want to note that there are other well-known ways of associating an ellipse to a polygon, including the matrix of second moments of the uniform distribution supported on the interior of the polygon and the so-called John ellipses, which are the ellipse of largest volume inscribed in the polygon and the one of smallest volume circumscribing the polygon.

Here is the ellipse we found: Given a polygon $P$ that contains the origin in its interior, let $\ell_1, \dots, \ell_n$ denote the lines that contain the sides of $P$. For each $i$, let $n_i$ denote the unit vector orthogonal to $\ell_i$, $h_i$ be the distance from the origin to the line $\ell_i$, and $s_i$ be the length of the side lying in $\ell_i$. For each $v \in R^2$, define

$ q(v) = \sum_{i=1}^n (v\cdot n_i)^2\frac{s_i}{h_i}. $

Let $E_P = \{ q(v) \le 1\}.$ The ellipse $E_P$ does not behave particularly nicely under translations of $P$. It however, behaves nicely under linear transformations. In particular, if $A$ is an invertible linear transformation with determinant $1$, then $E_{AP} = AE_P$. It is scale-invariant in that $E_{tP} = E_P$ for any $t > 0$.

The ellipse $E_P$ can in fact be defined without using the inner product and is a linear invariant of the polygon $P$. Its definition can be extended to any body $P$ containing the origin with a sufficiently regular boundary. It is an example of a matrix-valued valuation on the set of all convex bodies that contain the origin in their interior. Its volume is maximized if and only if the body $P$ is itself an ellipsoid centered at the origin.

Does anyone recognize this association of an ellipse to a polygon? I would be grateful for any information or references.

EDIT: Vladimir's comments below, especially the first sentence, indicate clearly that I omitted something crucial. The definition of the ellipsoid depends on the choice of the volume form in the ambient vector space (and the dual volume form in the dual vector space). Changing the volume form will rescale the ellipsoid by a factor. However, if you fix the volume form, then the ellipsoid is invariant under rescaling of the convex body.

This observation, however, makes the existence of a scale-invariant ellipsoid associated with the polygon much less surprising.

Answer (score 8):

Maybe it would have been more convincing if you had given the definition of $q_K$ in a unimodularly equivariant way from the beginning.  That's not at all hard to do, and it's also easy to see how to create many more such (and how to create many more in all dimensions).

For example, suppose $K\subset V$ has vertices $v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_n=v_0$ (cyclically ordered counterclockwise, say).  Let $\alpha_i\in V^\ast$ be the unique element that satisfies $\alpha_i(v_i)=\alpha_i(v_{i+1})=1$.  Then 
$$
q_K = \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} \Omega(v_i,v_{i+1})\ {\alpha_i}^2
$$
(where $\Omega$ is the area form.)  This is clearly unimodularly equivariant with respect to $K$ and, since, for $K' = tK$ (with $t>0$), one has $v'_i = tv_i$ and  $\alpha_i' = (1/t)\alpha_i$, it follows that $q_{tK} = q_K$.  Of course, anything like this would have worked.  For example, you could have taken
$$
\tilde q_K = Area_\Omega(K)\left( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}  {\alpha_i}^2\right),
$$
and this would also have had the same equivariance property.

In dimension $n$, I think that the right formula would be to define, for each face $F$ of $K$, the element $\alpha_F\in V^\ast$ to be the linear function that equals $1$ on $F$, let $\Omega(F)$ denote the volume of the cone with vertex $0\in V$ whose base is $F$, and then set
$$
q_K = \sum_{F\in\mathcal{F}(K)} \Omega(F)\ {\alpha_F}^2.
$$
If you want it to be invariant under scaling, you should take
$$
q_K = \sum_{F\in\mathcal{F}(K)} \Omega(F)^{2/n}\ {\alpha_F}^2.
$$
Perhaps, better, though, would be to take 
$$
q_K = Vol_\Omega(K)^{(2-n)/n}\ \left(\sum_{F\in\mathcal{F}(K)} \Omega(F)\ {\alpha_F}^2\right),
$$
since this is also invariant under subdivision of the faces of $K$.

Comment: Robert, you're right. I don't normally work directly with polytopes, and it's a little trickier to write down a integral that is obviously linearly equivariant. I do explain how to do this in the following paper: http://www.deaneyang.com/papers/affine_survey.pdf

Comment: Robert, am I happy you jumped in. I have never seen before the ellipsoids you define. If I understand correctly, most of them are defined only for polytopes and blow up if you take a limit to a continuous body. I knew of a complementary family that is defined for smooth convex bodies but vanishes for polytopes. Your family (defined by raising $\Omega(F)$ to powers less than 1) is well defined for polytopes but blow up (I believe) for polytopes. In particular, I don't see any way to define them using an integral (which is what I normally do).

Comment: Correction: "blow up for smooth convex bodies" (not polytopes)

Comment: The last formula, with $n = 2$, is exactly the one described in my question.

Comment: @Deane:  Actually, when $n=2$, it's one-half the one you gave (and also one-half the first unimodularly equivariant formula that I gave).  Yes, the other formulae (besides the last one) don't have any good convergence properties if you take a sequence of polygons that converge to some convex curve.  My point was just that there are lots of ways to define unimodularly equivariant ellipsoids associated to a polygon.  In fact, there are lots of ways to define such ellipsoids that are equivariant under the full unimodular affine group (including translations).  Have you asked Calabi your question?

Comment: Robert, I should probably try again, but I'm pretty sure we've asked Calabi about ellipsoids naturally associated with a convex body. By now we know different variations of the so-called Legendre ellipsoid as well as the one described above (and in our paper). But the ones you describe in your answer appear, surprisingly, to be new. I'm also curious about ellipsoids that are equivariant under translation. We know how to do this by just translating one of the ellipsoids described above so that its center of mass is the same as the convex body's. Do you have another way to get equivariance?

Comment: @Deane:  The center-of-mass method is the main one that I had in mind, but, in the case of strongly convex bodies, one can start with the unimodularly affine invariant measure on the boundary and multiply it by any positive function of the higher order invariants (for example, the Pick invariant plus 1) and use that measure to compute a 'center of 'mass'' that is *a priori* different from the usual center of mass.  The point being that there are several different possible 'canonical' centers.  BTW, most of the ellipsoids I defined above depend on the triangulation of $K$, not just $K$ itself.

Answer (score 6):

I am confused: is this not the construction in:

MR1781476 (2001j:52011) 
Lutwak, Erwin(1-PINY); Yang, Deane(1-PINY); Zhang, Gaoyong(1-PINY)
A new ellipsoid associated with convex bodies. 
Duke Math. J. 104 (2000), no. 3, 375–390. 
52A40 (52A39)

If so, why ask now :)

Comment: Igor, you are absolutely right. We defined this construction in any dimension in the paper cited. But we only recently noticed that in the plane the ellipse is invariant under rescaling of the body. We were curious about whether in dimension 2 the ellipse was already known to someone.

Answer (score 2):

(Just a question, not an answer.)
@Deane: Does the ellipse have a clear geometric relationship to the polygon?
I believe it is always a circle for a centered regular polygon.
For the equilateral triangle below, I compute
$$3 \sqrt{3} (x^2 + y^2 ) = 1$$
and for the right triangle, centered as illustrated,
$$6 x^2 + 4xy + 6y^2 = 1 \;.$$

   [image: Two examples]

Comment: The geometric relationship is expressed by the property that $E_{AP} = AE_P$ for any polygon $P$ and determinant 1 linear transformation $A$. In particular, if $P$ is invariant under a rotation of an angle other than 180 degrees, this implies that the ellipse is also invariant by the same rotation and therefore must be a circle.

Comment: One more comment: But among all shapes $P$ such that $E_P$ is a circle, the area enclosed by $E_P$ is maximized only if $P$ is itself a circle. But what's a little weird here is that the size of $E_P$, as well as its shape, is being determined by the shape but not the size of $P$.

Comment: @Deane: Thank you!  This is intriguing...

Answer (score 2):

Dear  Dean, Dear All,

This is hopefully the last (4th) edition of my answer.  I spend few hours in calculations which could be dismissed would I think a bit before doing them. I believe that now I understand what happens and what most of you probably knew before.

First of all, there exists no  canonical construction  $K\mapsto E_K$  of an ellipse by a convec body (I understand canonically as ``depends only on the linear structure and on $K$'')  such that  it satisfies  $E_{tK} =E_K$. The reason is that this would imply the existence of a canonical euclidean structure in a 2-dimensional space equipped with a  linear  complex structure, which is wrong because the group of the linear  transformations preserving a complex structure is bigger than the group of linear transformations preserving a  euclidean structure.

Indeed, consider a two-dimensional linear complex structure  on $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e., fix a  matrix $J$  such that  $J^2= -1$. The group of linear transformations  preserving the complex structure evidently  contains the scalings $(x,y)\mapsto \textrm{const} \cdot (x,y)$ and therefore can not preserve any euclidean structure.

Suppose there exists a  canonical construction of an ellipsoid $E_K$  by a convex  body $K$  such that  it behaves as follows w.r.t. to linear transformations:  for every linear transformation $A$ with $det(A)= 1$ we have $A E_K = E_{AK}$; for every scaling $S:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$,  $(x,y)\stackrel{S}\mapsto \textrm{const} \cdot (x,y)$  we have $E_{SK}= E_K$.  Then, we can construct a canonical  scalar product on our $\mathbb{R}^2$. Indeed, having $J$, we have a canonical notion of a circle centered at  $\vec 0$. More precisely, in every real linear 2dim-space we have the notion of an ellipse. 
 A circle around $\vec 0$ is an ellipse which is $J-$invariant.  As you see, in order to define an  ellipse  we used the linear structure of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the complex structure  $J$ only, so any linear  transformation that preserves $J$, in particular every
scaling $(x,y)\stackrel{S}\mapsto \textrm{const} \cdot (x,y)$  takes a circle centered at $\vec 0$ to a circle centered at $\vec 0$. 
round

Now suppose your construction $K\mapsto E_K$ exists. As  $K$, take the round ball centered at the origin.  The  freedom in choosing such a convex body  is its scaling $K\mapsto \textrm{const}\cdot K$; if  the construction do not depend on scaling  we obtain that the freedom in choosing  such a  convex body does not affect the 
ellipse $E_K$ (which must also be a circle because of the symmetry) 
  we obtain a canonical  inner product on $(\mathbb{R}^2, J)$. There is no such product though, by the  reasons I explained before: the group of complex transformations is bigger than the group of the orthogonal transformations.

Thus, there is no hope to construct a scaling-equivarinat   and  linear-transformations-invariant ellipse by a convex body in $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it must something be wrong with the announced properties of the construction from the question.  I should confess that first I thought  that the problem is with the invariance of the construction w.r.t. linear transformations, and bothered Deane and you all with attempts of counterexamples.

No, the problem is not with the behavior of the construction w.r.t. the linear transformations! The problem is that the construction is NOT CANONICAL. 
Indeed, it depends on the choice of the euclidean structure in the space: if you multiply the euclidean structure by a constant, the resulting ellipsoid will be the initial divided by the square of this constant!

Actually, since the   construction is indeed invariant w.r.t. to linear transformations with determinant  $1$, one can think that the information we need from the euclidean structure is its volume form only. This was pointed out by Deane to me in one of his comment, with a hint that normally should be sufficient for me to understand everything without doing the calculations.  It is also  stays inexplicit in the edited version of Deane's question.

By the way, the ``original'' version  of the construction in the paper MR1781476 (2001j:52011) Lutwak, Erwin(1-PINY); Yang, Deane(1-PINY); Zhang, Gaoyong(1-PINY) A new ellipsoid associated with convex bodies. Duke Math. J. 104 (2000), no. 3, 375–390. 52A40 (52A39) does have additional term  inside, which makes the construction to be volume-form-independent, but the resulting ellipse does not have the desired property $E_{tK}= E_K$ anymore.

Now, if you do not require the property $E_{tK}= E_K$, there exist tons of canonical constructions of an ellipse by a convex body. You  even can  do these construction the whole-affine-group-invariant, by first moving  the body such that  its barycenter is located in the origin of the coordinate system you are doing the construction  starting from.

[Edit record --1st attempt: added the explanation why it could not worked at all and corrected the counterexample] [Edit record -- 2nd attempt: the previous  counterexample did not work, now the new one that works is there]  [Edit record -- 3 attempt:One more unsuccesful counterexample] [Edit record: -- 4th attempt: explanation that the construction is not invariant]

Comment: Vladimir, thanks for your response. I will take a closer look when I get a chance. It could be that my description above isn't exactly right. If you're interested, you can look at the paper mentioned by Igor Rivin. Except possibly for a dilation factor, the ellipsoid is definitely equivariant under linear transformations. If you normalize the ellipsoid by a scale factor equal to the right power of the volume of the body, then it is equivariant, period.

Comment: Vladimir, when I do the calculation, I get $q(v) = 4[(v_1)^2 + (v_2)^2]$ for the square and $q(v) = 2[(v_1)^2 + 4(v_2)^2]$ for the image of the square under the map you give. This is consistent with my description of the ellipsoid. The transformation matrix can be factored into a scalar multiple of the diagonal and a matrix with determinant 1. The scalar multiple of the diagonal does not change the ellipsoid, but the matrix of determinant 1 does. Note that the volume of the new ellipsoid is the same as the volume of the original one.

Comment: Dean, I edited my ``answer'' without seeing your comment. I will redo your calculations. 

But in the newer version of my answer there is an explanation why you construction can not exist at all. I also changes the transformation in my counterexample slightly. Could you please look at it?  

Comment: I redid the calculation for your new transformation. I get $q_{AK}(v_1, v_2) = 16(v_1)^2 + (v_2)^2.$ So $q_{AK}(Av) = 16(v_1/2)^2 + (2v_2)^2 = 4(v_1)^2 + 4(v_2)^2 = q_K(v_1, v_2)$.

Comment: Here are some more details: For the square, the sides are $s_1 = s_2 = s_3 = s_4 = 2$ and the support function values are $h_1 = h_2 = h_3 = h_4 = 1$. For the rectangle, the corresponding values are $s_1 = s_3 = 4$, $s_2 = s_4 = 1$, $h_1 = h_3 = 1/2$, and $h_2 = h_4 = 2$.

Comment: Dean, let us together consider the square with side 2 centered at the origin and the  mapping $(x,y) \mapsto  (x/\sqrt{2}, \sqrt{2} \cdot y)$. This is my initial mapping scaling such that its determinant is $1$. We have the following sequences  of your data $[n,s,h]$ for the initial square and its image w.r.t. to this transformation: $[(1,0), 2,1], [(0,1), 2,1]$ for the square and  $[(1,0), 2\sqrt{2},1/\sqrt{2}], [(0,1), 2/\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2}]$ for image. Plugging these, we  have $q(v)= 4 v_1^2 + 4 v_2^2$ for the square and $q(v)= 16 v_1^2 + v_2^2$ for its image. One is not image of the other.

Comment: of course the construction cannot be **invariant**, it is **equivariant** just like the John or Legendre ellipsoids. 


Comment: In my understanding neither John nor Legendre ellipsoids are scaling-invariant. As I explained in my answer, there is no scaling-invariant canonical construction. Since the formula is evidently scaling-invariant (by scaling we multiply $s$ and $h$ by the same constant and do not change $n$), it can not be canonical. 

There should be some misunderstanding from my side, I should think a bit. 

Comment: As for your first sentence, I agree that my original description seems to imply this. However, the definition of the ellipsoid *does* depend on the choice of a volume form (this fact is well hidden in my description), and if there is a chosen volume form, then it is of course easy to normalize the size of the ellipsoid. This observation does make the scale-invariance of the ellipsoid less surprising. Many thanks for your comments.

Comment: Vladimir, the map you describe in your comment is not the same as the one you give in your answer. I did the calculations for $A(x,y) = (x/2, 2y)$ and got $q_{AK}(x/2, y) = q_K(x,y)$.

Comment: Dear Deane, First of all,  sorry  indeed for wrong counterexamples. I edited my answer again and now it is (hopefully) the correct counterexample. When I get to the scanner I attach the picture as well. 
There is no volume form in your formula so your explanations in the pre-previous comment does not work. You formula is scaling-invariant, so it can not be $Sl$-invariant. Please look on the (last version) of the counterexample. 

Comment: Vladimir, my description of the ellipsoid uses normal vectors, so it is using the inner product of $R^2$. If you study how the ellipsoid behaves under linear transformations, you find that it really depends only on the volume form induced by the inner product. I'm sorry but I'm quite busy these days, so I'll take a closer look at your example when I get a chance. But you might want to look at *my* calculations and tell me what I did wrong.

Comment: Here's a simple exercise: Rescale the inner product and use the new inner product to construct the ellipsoid. You'll get a new ellipsoid that is a scaled version of the original one.

Comment: Vladimir, I really think you're confusing "invariant" and "equivariant". The affine group acts on the space of convex bodies in $R^n$, it also acts on the set of ellipsoids in $R^n$. The John ellipsoid, the Legendre ellipsoid with respect to the barycenter, and the Lutwak-Yang-Zhang ellipsoid are equivariant maps between these two spaces. That's all.

Comment: Dear Deane,  
I put the link to the picture related to the counterexample. I hope it would help you when you have time to check whether it is indeed a counterexample. 

I did not understand your last two  comments, sorry.  Though you do use the inner product of $R^2$, you claim that the construction is invariant with respect to the group $Sl_2$. In my counterexample, the dependence of the ellipsoid on the linear transformations is not as you claim. It does behave as you claim under the re-scalings, which was clear from the very beginning,  and rescaling of the inner product would not help me.

Comment: Vladimir, I'm sorry but I'm quite busy these days. Moreover, I am quite confident of everything I wrote above, which is taken directly from the paper mentioned in Igor's answer to this question. Moreover, I have shown that your first two counterexamples were not counterexamples. At this point, I no longer have the time or desire to keep checking your claims of new counterexamples. It doesn't help that you keep dismissing my comments and explanations. I'm willing to have us agree to disagree (you think our paper is wrong; I don't).

Comment: But I will repeat that I am grateful for your answer and comments, because it did help me understand why the ellipsoid is in fact not as remarkable as I thought when I posted the question. As alvarezpaiva says, it's just another ellipsoid associated with a convex body that, like the Legendre ellipsoid, is linearly equivariant. Its definition does not depend on the inner product of $R^n$, but definitely requires a choice of a volume form on $R^n$. I in fact prefer to think of a convex body as lying in an abstract vector space, rather than $R^n$, and define the ellipsoid in that setting.

Comment: I don't understand why someone down voted @Vladimir's answer...

Comment: Igor, if you can explain why Vladimir is right and I am wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Vladimir, I suspect that in the end we agree on what's true, but somehow we are expressing things differently and are not understanding each other properly. I agree with almost everything you say in your latest answer, but none of it contradicts anything I have said in my comments.

Comment: No, non of my current understanding  contradicts your comments and would I read them more carefully and  spend more time thinking about them I could probably save  few hours of calculations. 

Would you say directly that the construction is not canonic it would be easier for me to understand the matter. 

Anyway it is a nice construction and it was a fun  to think about it :-)

Comment: To alvarezpaiva: 

If you look on the initial question of Deane, you can see that it is indeed does not change if we   scale of the convex body -- simply look on the formula. It is because it does not coincide with the Lutwak-Yang-Zhang construction, the difference is a factor which makes the Lutwak-Yang-Zhang construction canonic. I do not think that I confusing "invariant" and "equivariant", especially because in all editions of my answer I supported the words by formulas

Comment: @Vladimir: I did not understand your insistance on *invariance* : it is easy to see that such construction cannot exist, even if you restrict its domain to ellipsoids. Formulas have little to do with this. 

Comment: Juan Carlos, I do not insist on invariance or equivariance, I insist that I am not confusing something, at least now. I did have some problems from the very beginning, and it seems that youe are  repeating  my way and make the same mistaked. If you want we can stop this discussion, of cause; if now, please explain me what you understand under  ``such'' in your last comment.  